# How to use tailwindcss to change the color of each element when hovering over descendant elements

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to change the text color when I hover each a tag, but the text color changes when I hover the ul tag.

I would like to know how the text color changes when I hover over each a tag.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<ul class="flex gap-3 [&_a]:block [&_a]:text-blue-500 [&_a]:hover:text-red-500">
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/">foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/">bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/">baz</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="bg-orange-100 border-l-4 border-orange-500 text-orange-700 p-4 mt-10 mb-3">
  <p class="font-bold">Please</p>
  <p>I would like to use a method other than the one below.</p>
</div>
<ul class="flex gap-3 [&_a]:block [&_a]:text-blue-500">
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/" class="hover:text-red-500">foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/" class="hover:text-red-500">bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/" class="hover:text-red-500">baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `:hover` inside the arbitrary variant (replace `[&_a]:hover:text-red-500` with `[&_a:hover]:text-red-500`).

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<ul class="flex gap-3 [&_a]:block [&_a]:text-blue-500 [&_a:hover]:text-red-500">
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/">foo</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/">bar</a></li>
  <li><a href="https://www.example.com/">baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you very much!